# Closed-forms of the integrals $\int_0^1 K(\sqrt{k})^2 \, dk$, $\int_0^1 E(\sqrt{k})^2 \, dk$ and $\int_0^1 K(\sqrt{k}) E(\sqrt{k}) \, dk$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, closed-form, elliptic-integrals

Let denote $K$ and $E$ the [complete elliptic integral of the first](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html) and [second kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteEllipticIntegraloftheSecondKind.html).

The integrand $K(\sqrt{k})$ and $E(\sqrt{k})$ has a closed-form antiderivative in term of $K(\sqrt{k})$ and $E(\sqrt{k})$, so we know that
$$
\int_0^1 K\left(\sqrt{k}\right) \, dk = 2,
$$
and
$$
\int_0^1 E\left(\sqrt{k}\right) \, dk = \frac{4}{3}.
$$

I couldn't find closed-form antiderivatives to the integrals $\int K(\sqrt{k})^2 \, dk$, $\int E(\sqrt{k})^2 \, dk$, $\int E(\sqrt{k})K(\sqrt{k}) \, dk$, but I've conjectured, that

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 K\left(\sqrt{k}\right)^2 \, dk &\stackrel{?}{=} \frac{7}{2}\zeta(3),\\
\int_0^1 E\left(\sqrt{k}\right)^2 \, dk &\stackrel{?}{=} \frac{7}{8}\zeta(3)+\frac{3}{4},\\
\int_0^1 K\left(\sqrt{k}\right)E\left(\sqrt{k}\right) \, dk &\stackrel{?}{=} \frac{7}{4}\zeta(3)+\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}$$

How could we prove this closed-forms? It would be nice to see some references to these integrals.

Comment: highly interesting question (+1)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568615/conjectured-closed-form-for-int-01x2-q-1-kx2dx-where-kx-is-the-c?rq=1
This will be quite interesting for you

Comment: It looks like it is just a matter of computing $$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dk}{\sqrt{1-kt^2}\sqrt{1-ks^2}}$$ through Legendre's identity, then integrate it against $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-s^2}\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ over $(0,1)^2$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio i tried that, but this leads to a dead end... :(

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/704818/19661) might be related question.

Answer (score 10):

We have
$$ K(\sqrt{k}) = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-k t^2}}\tag{1} $$
hence:
$$ K(\sqrt{k})^2 = \iint_{(0,1)^2}\frac{dt\,ds}{\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{1-s^2}\sqrt{(1-kt^2)(1-ks^2)}}\tag{2}$$
and since:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{dk}{\sqrt{(1-ks^2)(1-kt^2)}}&=&\frac{1}{st}\int_{0}^{st}\frac{dk}{\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{s}{t}+\frac{t}{s}\right)k+k^2}}\\&=&\frac{1}{st}\,\left.\log\left(2k-\left(\frac{s}{t}+\frac{t}{s}+2\sqrt{k^2-\left(\frac{s}{t}+\frac{t}{s}\right)k+1}\right)\right)\right|_{0}^{st}\\&=&\frac{1}{st}\,\log\left(\frac{t^2+s^2-2t^2 s^2-2st\sqrt{(1-s^2)(1-t^2)}}{(s-t)^2}\right)\tag{3}\end{eqnarray*}$$
it follows that:

$$ \int_{0}^{1}K(\sqrt{k})^2\,dk = \iint_{\left(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^2}\log\left[\frac{\sin^2(\phi-\theta)}{(\sin\phi-\sin\theta)^2}\right]\cot(\phi)\cot(\theta)\,d\phi\,d\theta$$
and now we may use a change of coordinates and the [Fourier series of $\log\sin$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292468/fourier-series-of-log-sine-and-log-cos).

An interesting chance is also given by exploiting the expansion of $K(k)$ with respect to the base of $L^2(0,1)$ given by the [shifted Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Shifted_Legendre_polynomials). We have:
$$ K(k) = 2\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{P_n(2k-1)}{2n+1}\tag{4} $$
and since:
$$ \int_{0}^{1}P_n(2\sqrt{k}-1)^2\,dk = \frac{1}{2n+1},$$
$$ \int_{0}^{1}P_n(2\sqrt{k}-1)P_{n+1}(2\sqrt{k}-1)\,dk=\frac{n+1}{(2n+1)(2n+3)}\tag{5}$$
we have:
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{1}K(\sqrt{k})^2\,dk&=&4\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)^3}+8\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{n+1}{(2n+1)^2(2n+3)^2}\\&=&\color{red}{\frac{7}{2}\,\zeta(3)+1}.\tag{6}\end{eqnarray*}$$

This is the same approach used by [Zhou](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1301.1735) to prove similar identities.